# Camel Java API handling wrong data format

Tags: java, apache-camel

What is the way for handling errors in case when body is like that:

```
{
    "someEnum1": "A",
    "someEnum2": "B",
    "someDate1": "test"
}
```

And when possible enum values are for example X and Y, so A and B are unparsable. And date "test" also cannot be parsed. How to handle it properly and return information which field is wrong with HTTP code 400 (how to validate those fields) ?

```
 rest(API_CONTEXT + V1)
                .post(API_OPERATION)
                .type(RequestModel.class)
                .outType(Response.class)
                .consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .to(MY_ROUTE);
```

RequestModel has `someEnum1`, `someEnum2` and `someDate1` fields. So such body won't marshal to object.

OnException pattern in Camel is propably a wrong way as I won't be able to figure which field had problem withc parsin? And my response object has `errorCode` and `errorDescription` that says which field is wrong.

Comment: By using `.type(...)` and  `.outType(...)` you tell Camel to use the defined object mapper (i.e. Jackson) to convert the JSON representation to a POJO and vice versa. Jackson should use [`Enum.valueOf(enumType, name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-) to perform the String value to POJO conversion of that enum value for you, which will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the string is not defined as constant in that enum. If you don't catch this exception you will get back a `500 Internal Server Error` as response

Comment: [Further suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49010933/apache-camel-rest-dsl-validating-request-payload-and-return-error-response) on how to deal create custom error responses